# Anchor Conflicting Scripts

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I currently have two scripts affecting each other. The script shown underneath is doing smooth scroll to anchors. My second script links to a lightbox effect using an a href # anchor. Can I change the script below to use something different than href and #?

Javascript

```
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var lengthDiv = $('.desktop').find('li').length;
var current = 0;
$('a').bind('click',function(event){

var $anchor = $(this);
current = $anchor.parent().index();

$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
/*
if you don't want to use the easing effects:
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 1000);
*/
event.preventDefault();
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){e.preventDefault()})
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key == 38 && current > 0){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current - 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }else if(key == 40 && current < lengthDiv){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current + 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
$('a').bind('click', function(){})
```

Is going to attach a click event to every "a" tag. If you want it to attach to a different element or selector, you have to change it.

```
$('a.scroll').bind('click', function(){})
```

As an example.